# Django - download file to client after POST request

Tags: django, python-2.7, file-upload, django-forms

I'm new with Django and im working on a form where you can upload an xlsx file, the server does some manipulations to it and then returns the edited version of your xlsx. For now, i'm just testing some basic stuff so all i want to do after i upload my file is return a CSV file that i've created

Thing is, I'm trying to return the new file but the file doesn't get downloaded as a a file, it is simply returned by the server and you can only see it in the "network" tab where you can see the information about the page you're on in your browser.

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = UploadFile(file = request.FILES['file'])
            new_file.save()
            response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'text/csv')
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
            writer.writerow(['"hello"', '"2"'])
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.csv"'
            return response
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form}   
    return render_to_response('index2.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Upload a file in Django 1.5 using Dropzone.js</title>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- IMPORTANT enctype attribute! -->
        <form class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
        <button id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit all files
        </button>

        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}dropzone.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

                // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
                autoProcessQueue : false,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                removedfile: function(file) {
    var _ref;
    console.log((_ref = file.previewElement) != null);
    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
  },
                init : function() {
                    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    console.log(myDropzone);
                    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                        // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                    });

                    // You might want to show the submit button only when
                    // files are dropped here:
                    this.on("addedfile", function() {
                        // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                    });

                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen and what do i have to do to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: so the only issue i can see is  `response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.csv"`, get rid of the quotes

Comment: still doesnt work, but if i paste the part of creating the HttpResponse instead of the render_to_response part or in the 'else' part, it works

Comment: Have you tried setting the content disposition on the response before passing the response to the csv writer?

Comment: I hadn't but i've tried it now and it doens't work :(
It's really werid though because if i put this piece of code anywhere that isn't in the if request.method=='POST', it does work

Answer (score 0):

Method to send a csv file on the client side

```
def _download(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="text/csv", charset="utf-8")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```